# Is it possible to insert multiple records in Salesforce using cURL at the same time?

Tags: rest-api, salesforce-id

I am using cURL to insert data into salesforce. It works with single record but I need to insert multiple records at a time. Is it possible to do so and is it possible via a REST interface?

Comment: Hi, Could you please correct me with regard to the cURL command line that I'm using for inserting a record into Salesforce: curl -H "Authorization: Bearer sessionId" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @account.txt "https://instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account/"

I'm unable to do the insert as I'm unaware to use "account.txt" file, if I needed to give any path location to the above command line. 

By the way, I'm following the example provided in Salesforce http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm

Comment: Hi Sapthagiri ,,Instead of account.txt use .json File Format ,because Here The Content Type you Mentioned is  json Type .

Comment: When I'm sending the following cURL command,
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer access_token' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @D:\notes.json 'https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Notes__c/' client_id=client_id --form client_secret=secret
I am getting the following error
    Warning: Couldn't read data from file "D:notes.json", this makes an empty
    Warning: POST.
    Warning: You can only select one HTTP request!

Comment: Here is a example curl -H "Authorization:OAuth 00D90000000kwMw!AQYAQE09Is.2ZGr7qvAqGPz8.0y1fnEfQJJluW3yAV9nPNtMw6M1OrnCKsMmGUPC495DU95Nq83sI3qja3m6NLo3TAdePlZ9" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @newaccount.json "https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/"

Comment: Hi Vineeth, do we need to have this "newaccount.json" at any particular location & how are we supposed to provide this path. Actually, I'm trying to execute these cURL commands in https://apigee.com/console & I'm struck with the following error message: 
{
  "error_description": "grant type not supported",
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type"
}

Comment: No Need .It Can Be on any location ,just we need to specify the Path

Comment: Hi, I've created a file named "newaccount.json" which has got { "Account Name" : "Test Account"} and has given the path as -d @D:\newaccount.json. And when running the command line, I'm getting an error named **Warning: Couldn't read data from file "newaccount.json", this makes an empty
Warning: POST.
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]**

Comment: And one more thing, do you have any idea on how to execute this in https://apigee.com/console/salesforce as it would be bit more helpful.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12322/discussion-between-vineeth-and-sapthagiri)

Answer (score 9):

You can't insert multiple rows in a single call in the rest api, you need to use the bulk api.

You can develop custom REST wrapper webservice through APEX language of sfdc to get this set up

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/insertcontact/*')

global with sharing class Mycontacts{

 @HttpPost
  global static List<Contact> doPost(List<Contact> lstcnts){
      insert lstcnts;
      return lstcnts;
   }

}
```

> This is pretty raw version.You can follow best practices and track successful Ids and failed records .
>
> If there are two much of records i would suggest you to use BULK API of sfdc as the REST API has size limitations and all apex governor limits apply

Edit

As per latest update this is now possible with tree API provided

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm

Comment: Hi mohith do you have any reference code for inserting multiple records using rest api ..it wl be helpfull if you do so ...

Comment: What do you mean by reference code here.The above code will work and you can test with curl.The url will be instanceurl/services/apexrest/insertcontact.Where instance url is your salesforce instance url

Comment: Hi Mohith, I am inserting  a single record with REST call.. How would be the json request if I want to insert the multiple records with REST ..

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava Can you please update your answer with latest update  s for creating multiple records using rest API . Please see this doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm this will help other to understand this is possible now

Answer (score 3):

As with my answer to [How to Insert/Update multiple records in a single Force.com REST API call?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/75660/102) there are some interesting details in [Knowledge Article Number: 000214070 - Summer `15 - REST API Updates](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000214070&language=en_US).

There is going to be a new Batch resource where you can send multiple sub-requests and get a separate sub-response back for each.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. I almost started writing Apex REST API and came across this post.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, please have a look at the official documentation with its example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm

Answer (score 0):

As of API v42.2 you can now use the [SObject Collections Composite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections.htm) endpoints.  There are two major benefits over the existing composite tree & batch endpoints.

1: You can update up to 200 records at a time

2: The updates take place in a single execution context on salesforce.  The other composite record create a context PER RECORD, which make it run incredibly slow for big updates.