# How to insert multiple records in an object using REST API post method in workbench

Tags: rest-api, post

By providing following uri and by using following Request Body, we can insert a single record in a sObject

```
uri: /services/data/v36.0/sobjects/sObject
Request Body : {
"field1" :"value1",
"field2" :"value2"
}
```

But, how to insert multiple records in an object using post method in workbench?
Could any one please suggest me.

Comment: It is possible.See [Ratan's answer here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123108/can-we-insert-multiple-records-in-sobject-using-rest-api-post-method-without-usi).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Create Multiple Records using rest API

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm)

> While the SObject Tree resource can be used to create nested records,
>   you can also create multiple, unrelated records of the same type. In a
>   single request, you can create up to two hundred records. In the
>   request data, you supply the required and optional field values for
>   each record, each record’s type, and a reference ID for each record,
>   and then use the POST method of the resource. The response body will
>   contain the IDs of the created records if the request is successful.
>   Otherwise, the response contains only the reference ID of the record
>   that caused the error and the error information.

We need to use below end point

```
/services/data/v34.0/composite/tree/Account/
```

And request body will be something like this

```
{
"records" :[{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref1"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount1",
    "phone" : "1111111111",
    "website" : "www.salesforce1.com",
    "numberOfEmployees" : "100",
    "industry" : "Banking"   
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref2"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount2",
    "phone" : "2222222222",
    "website" : "www.salesforce2.com",
    "numberOfEmployees" : "250",
    "industry" : "Banking"
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref3"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount3",
    "phone" : "3333333333",
    "website" : "www.salesforce3.com",
    "numberOfEmployees" : "52000",
    "industry" : "Banking"
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref4"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount4",
    "phone" : "4444444444",
    "website" : "www.salesforce4.com",
    "numberOfEmployees" : "2500",
    "industry" : "Banking"
    }]
}
```

Comment: @SKumaran you're welcome ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to create/update multiple records in a single call via the REST API.

Please follow the below SFSE link to know more about this.

SFSE Link - [Is it possible to insert multiple records in Salesforce using cURL at the same time?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21478/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-records-in-salesforce-using-curl-at-the-same-t)