# Can we insert multiple records in sObject using REST API post method without using apex class in workbench or postman

Tags: rest-api, post

```
/services/data/v36.0/sobject/ObjectName
and 
{
"name" : "some name",
"Description" : "Some Description"
}
```

By using above uri and request body we can insert a single record in object with post method in workbench or in postman also.

But **how to insert multiple records in object using same post method?**

Comment: check this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Create Multiple Records using rest API

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm)

> While the SObject Tree resource can be used to create nested records,
>   you can also create multiple, unrelated records of the same type. In a
>   single request, you can create up to two hundred records. In the
>   request data, you supply the required and optional field values for
>   each record, each record’s type, and a reference ID for each record,
>   and then use the POST method of the resource. The response body will
>   contain the IDs of the created records if the request is successful.
>   Otherwise, the response contains only the reference ID of the record
>   that caused the error and the error information.

We need to use below end point url

```
/services/data/v34.0/composite/tree/Account/
```

And request body will be something like this

```
{
"records" :[{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref1"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount1",
    "phone" : "1111111111",
    "website" : "www.salesforce1.com",
    "numberOfEmployees" : "100",
    "industry" : "Banking"   
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref2"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount2",
    "phone" : "2222222222",
    "website" : "www.salesforce2.com",
    "numberOfEmployees" : "250",
    "industry" : "Banking"
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref3"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount3",
    "phone" : "3333333333",
    "website" : "www.salesforce3.com",
    "numberOfEmployees" : "52000",
    "industry" : "Banking"
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref4"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount4",
    "phone" : "4444444444",
    "website" : "www.salesforce4.com",
    "numberOfEmployees" : "2500",
    "industry" : "Banking"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Ratan awesome post.Can you close [this post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123015/how-to-insert-multiple-records-in-an-object-using-rest-api-post-method-in-workbe) also.It has same question.

Comment: @Mr.Frodo thanks I have posted in other question as well.

Comment: Hi @Ratan, I have a doubt 
what is the need of using referenceId?
Can you explain me please......

Comment: @KSKumar referenceId used to identify the records. For example if you are inserting 4 records and 2 are successful and 2 records hit error. So for newly created record you can identify using RecordId but for rest 2 record which are failed you can identify using referenceId.  **The response body will contain the IDs of the created records if the request is successful. Otherwise, the response contains only the reference ID of the record that caused the error and the error information**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40255/discussion-between-ks-kumaar-and-ratan).