# Insert/Update multiple records in salesforce using webservice

Tags: soap-api, partner-wsdl, apex-webservice, enterprise-wsdl

What are the possible way by which external system can insert/update multiple records in salesforce without writing any apex webservice. If webservice is required how it can be implemented. Please provide a sample code.

Comment: check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/how-to-insert-update-multiple-records-in-a-single-force-com-rest-api-call/75660#75660

Answer (score 1):

See the treesave API pilot:

It lets you save records in hierarchy via the rest API.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has a native [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/) and [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/) that allows inserting and updating multiple records. The documentation for both APIs include "Quick Start" sections with sample code that should get you going.

Comment: Thanks Marty C. I want external system should be able to insert/update a parent and related child record in a single request to Salesforce. Will that be possible using these APIs?

Comment: You'll need to make two calls, one to insert/update the parent, and then a second call to insert/update the children.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without writing any apex web service in Salesforce. If I provide partner wsdl to client, will they be able to insert/update records in Salesforce.

Comment: Yes. If you use the SOAP API and use the WSDL, and you have software or middleware that can configure itself using the WSDL you won't have to write any code. You don't have to write an Apex web service.

Comment: Note that the REST API does *not* allow you to insert multiple records, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that's been omitted from the other responses to this question is that multi-record updates typically involve the use of some kind of wrapper class. So, even if someone has your WSDL, unless their service will work with the standard Apex Web Services classes (using your WSDL), any kind of custom service will involve either some kind of "middleware" on their end or creating a class that can process (or "accumulate") the inbound call into a list that Apex can parse/handle via what's essentially a wrapper class. That's the essence of how outbound multiple records are sent, so code that's essentially the equivalent needs to be configured to handle the records as they arrive on this end.